# Add to Favorites Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

What I want to do in Javascript/Jquery is be able to click a button (a button on each item), that adds it to an array. This array will then be posted in order when you click on a favorites page.

I'm just having a hard time wrapping my head around how this would work. Because I may want each item in the array to contain a few things, such as a picture and text describing the item.

In general terms/examples, how would this be set up?

Comment: I know that at least with JSON, I would have an array of objects. Then each object could have an array itself (not to mention other non-array properties).

Comment: Are you using any server-side scripts?

Comment: No, just doing this for practice on my computer.

Comment: What do you mean by "click on a favorites page"? Do you mean that they should be viewable on a separate page on the site or just a pop up within the same page?

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this. But, I'll go with one that's a bit *more* general - which you can extend for yourself:

http://jsfiddle.net/TEELr/11/

HTML:
This simply creates different elements with the favorite class - which will be the selector by which we check if an element has been clicked.

```
<div class="favorite"><p>Add to favorites</p></div>
<div class="favorite type2"><p>Just another favorite type</p></div>

<button id="reveal">
    Reveal Favorites
</button>
```

JS:

Every time an element with the "favorite" CSS class is clicked, it is added to the array - this also works for elements with more than one class (that have the "favorite" CSS class).

**Now, when the "Reveal Favorites" button is clicked, it will alert what's in the array - which is in the order clicked (as asked).**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var favorites = [];
    var counter = 0;

    $('.favorite').click(function() {
        ++counter;
        favorites.push("\"" + $(this).text() + " " + counter + "\"");
    });

    $('#reveal').click(function() {
       alert(favorites); 
    });
});
```

CSS:

Simple CSS that only exist for demonstration purposes to prove previous point with multiple CSS class selectors:

```
.favorite {
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.favorite.type2 {
    background-color: #ff3;
}

.favorite:hover {
    cursor:hand;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: This example of course, **can be adapted to support JSON as well**.